# Problema al mostrar eventos full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Mi calendario de full calendar no muestra los eventos
Os muestro mi código

Tengo el siguiente error

`lang-all.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at lang-all.js:1
    at lang-all.js:1`

El calendario funciona correctamente, se muestra en español y no hay problemas. Sólamente con mostrar los eventos

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['dayGrid'],
        locale: 'es',
        height: 'auto',
        events: [
          {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2019-10-10'
          }
        ]
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
  </script>
```

```html
<link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/core/locales/es.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/lang-all.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿le añadiste jquery como dependencia?